# How do you copy a file from the Domain Controller to a macos device that is joined to AD with powershell

Tags: macos, powershell, active-directory

Is it possible to copy a file with powershell to an AD joined macOS device? I know it is possible with Windows e.g.

copy-item -Path SOURCEFOLDER -Destination "\\$computer\\c$"

Is such command also possible for macOS?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - note that, due to lack of formatting, the ``\\`` in your command renders as just ``\``

Answer (score 0):

What makes this work on Windows is a combination of SMB/CIFS file share protocol and Kerberos authentication inside the domain.

If the mac has SSH enabled you could use `scp` to copy files to it.

If the mac has PowerShell with PS Remoting, you could make a new-pssession and then use copy-item to copy over that session.

Or you could enable SMB file sharing on the mac following [this Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1657/mac).

The syntax of `c$` would need to change, as macOS does not use driveletters. You may need to share a specific folder and arrange the permissions for you to copy into.